# OAuth2ClientContext is not accessible when handling /error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2

I'm setting up a spring cloud application with OAuth2 sso. I have set up a spring boot application named user-service and provided an OAuth2 authentication server.

I also set up another spring boot application named demo-service as a resource server application and have successfully gotten access to the demo-service in the scenario where my controllers do not throw any exceptions.

But when my controllers throw an exception, I will receive a 401 Unauthorized response (said that I have provided an invalid token, but the log has illustrated that my controller has worked correctly and throw an exception) instead of a 500 Internal Error response with message about the exception.

I have stepped into the source code of spring-security-oauth2 and spring-boot-autoconfigure-oauth2. I find that if my controllers throws an exception, the exception would be catched by the embeded tomcat server and forwarded to /error (which defined in application.yml with property server.error.path), but even if I set that /error needn't to be authenticated (I have confirmed that I can get access with /error without any credentials like access_token), I still cannot receive the 500 Internal Error.

I have searched the google and found an issue in Github:[Issue 84](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth2-boot/issues/84). After "solved" the issue, they suggested to add /error to not authenticate but it doesn't work on me.

The version of spring-cloud I using is GreenWich.RELEASE, with dependency plugins, the Maven provided spring-security-oauth2:2.3.3.RELEASE and spring-boot-autoconfigure-oauth2:2.1.0.M4. Here are some related configurations:

The dependencies I added to pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Boot Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Cloud -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Eureka -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Security -->
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- OAuth2 -->
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MyBatis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MySQL-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Greenwich.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

The main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@MapperScan(basePackages = {"demo.mapper"})
public class DemoServiceApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

resource server configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private ServerProperties serverProperties;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/error").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

a simple controller that will produce an exception:

```
@RestController
public class DemoController{
    @GetMapping
    public void testMethod(){
    // this can be run correctly and get the right principal information from user-service

 //System.out.println(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getPrincipal());
        throw new RuntimeException("some message wanted to see in 500 response");
    }    
}
```

the application.yml. I think if I can get access with controller's methods, the yml configuration probaly has no errors.

```
server:
  port: 8002
spring:
  application:
    name: demo-service
  datasource:
    # some jdbc configuration
mybatis:
  #some mybatis configuration
eureka:
  #eureka configuration

security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      access-token-uri: http://localhost:8000/oauth/token
      client-id: webclient
      client-secret: webclientsecret
    resource:
      user-info-uri: http://localhost:8000/user/current
      prefer-token-info: false
      service-id: user-service
logging:
  level:
    org: debug
```

If I send a request to /error directly, I can receive a correct json response(which was generated in BaseErrorController)
But if I send to my controller and be forwarded to /error I got these:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_token",
    "error_description": "<ACCESS_TOKEN>"
}
```

and an unusual log output:

```
DEBUG - [T2] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Received [GET / HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.13.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Host: localhost:8002
cookie: JSESSIONID=<JSESSIONID>
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: close

]
...
ERROR - [T2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: some message wanted to see in 500 response] with root cause

java.lang.RuntimeException: some message wanted to see in 500 response
    at demo.controller.DemoController.testMethod(DemoController.java:53) ~[classes/:na]
    ....

DEBUG - [T2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
...
DEBUG - [T2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter'
DEBUG - [T2] o.s.b.a.s.o.r.UserInfoTokenServices      : Getting user info from: http://localhost:8000/user/current
 WARN - [T2] o.s.b.a.s.o.r.UserInfoTokenServices      : Could not fetch user details: class org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException, Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.oauth2ClientContext': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
DEBUG - [T2] o.s.b.a.s.o.r.UserInfoTokenServices      : userinfo returned error: Could not fetch user details
DEBUG - [T2] p.a.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter : Authentication request failed: error="invalid_token", error_description="<ACCESS_TOKEN>"
DEBUG - [T2] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=2019-06-06T04:59:03.634Z, principal=access-token, type=AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException, message=<ACCESS_TOKEN>}]
DEBUG - [T2] s.s.o.p.e.DefaultOAuth2ExceptionRenderer : Written [error="invalid_token", error_description="<ACCESS_TOKEN>"] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@9b22a11]
DEBUG - [T2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
DEBUG - [T2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    :  Disabling the response for further output
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solve the problem by adding a RequestContextListener Bean to Spring container:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(RequestContextListener.class)
public RequestContextListener requestContextListener(){
    return new ReqeustContextListener();
}
```

and I paused the JVM in debug mode and searched the memory and find that there is only one RequestContextListener.
But why there will lack a RequestContextListener in Spring Boot Web application?